# change the doc root of the webserver to the custom location in weblogic 10

Tags: webserver, weblogic12c, weblogic-10.x

I have a prod setup where EAR application has jars, wars, ejb's but no static files like HTML, XML, js, vxml etc inside ear/war.
However these static files are kept in a custom directory outside weblogic dir. On successful ear deployment the application is able to render the static files which was placed outside war.

My observations below
I don't find any configs for virtual directory mapping and don't see any exploded war deployed in weblogic console either.

However I found a soft link which is pointed to the static files location of my application, and i believe my application requests are incoming to this softlink dir which redirects to my static content dir and these are delivered successfully.

But my question is how this soft link gets these requests which was triggered to my application. While googling around this topic i came to know changing the doc root of web server will help, so any pointers on this would be helpful.

The folder structure is below
My ear file location:

```
/apps/opt/voiceportal/app_name/app
```

All my app static files location

```
/apps/opt/voiceportal/app_name/web
```

Soft.link to.my static files

```
/apps/opt/voiceportal/web/app_name --> /apps/opt/voiceportal/app_name/web
```

Weblogic domain location

```
/apps/opt/weblogic/config/domain_name
```